# time step for Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-approximation

Given a stochastic differential equation:

$$
dx=a(x,t)dt+b(x,t)dW(t)
$$

where $x$ is a random variable, $a(x,t)$ is a function of $x$ and $t$; called drift term, and $b(x,t)$ is the diffusion term. Brownian motion is $dW(t)$.

Is there a relationship between the time increment $dt$ and the time step for Brownian motion? In another way is it correct that:
$$
\delta t=\sqrt dt
$$
where $\delta t$ is Brownian motion time step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rough words, so you can confirm your intuition, if you were asked to simulate the process on a timegrid (a bunch of "dt"), you will simulate $dW_t$ using $dW_t=\sqrt{dt}Y$ where Y is normally distributed (mean 0, variance 1).

Comment: I have read about the way of simulate this a long time ago. But I am looking for whether, there is a theorem that proves such a relation between time step dt and the Brownian motion time step $\delta t$.